# Where to ask a question about how an app works?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know how a particular application for **iOS** works.
I only need that what frameworks/libraries might have been used to built that app.

Where can I ask such a question?

Comment: The authors of the app, their website or community. Also the app's iOS documentation might list third party libraries (often because by using them they're legally required to mention that fact).

Comment: I thought so , but then why would the authors want to disclose anything about how their app works. Also in this case , the app doesn't list using an of the libraries.

Comment: Most authors do, in my experience. Knowing what libraries they use is a long mile from building a competitive product. The hard work is *execution*, not the idea. But if they won't tell you and the documentation doesn't say (bearing in mind, again, that many lobsters *require* a mention, and if they're not mentioning any then either they're not using such libraries or they're in breach), then I'm afraid you're out of luck. There is no stack in the network that will welcome and answer such questions. You'll mostly get a hostile response.

Comment: Yes , I also  think that no stack would entertain such a question. 
Thanks for the response..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Currently, we do not have any sites in the SE universe which would take this question.**

This question will be very broad, and highly dependent on guess-work. So, it is also not a great example of a StackExchange-style post.

> I only need that what frameworks/libraries might have been used to built that app

Due to the rise in the number of frameworks and libraries these days, there can be multiple guesses(/answers) for such a question. And, on top of that, this question can **never** have an accepted answer, cause all the answers would be pure guesswork, unless and until the author of the app answers it.

Answer (score 2):

On [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/), you can ask about how to examine the contents of an .ipa archive.  That said, your question has to ask about the technique; you will be doing the analysis yourself.